# Is a plastic bag torn or ripped?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

If we refer to a plastic bag (or fabric bag) that its content went outside due to a an heavy weight which the bag can't carry. Which one is more natural?

> The fruits fell down on the street's ground because the bag was **torn**.
>
> The fruits fell down on the street's ground because the bag was **ripped**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we refer to a plastic bag (or fabric bag) that its content went outside due to a an heavy weight which the bag can't carry. Which one is more natural?

There are a few things that could be improved in the OP's question, other than choosing which verb is preferable.

> **When** we talk about a plastic bag that breaks due to its weight, which word is more common: *rip* or *tear*?

The OP's sample sentence
*The fruits fell down on the street's ground because the bag was torn.*

The sample sentence is comprehensible but unnatural sounding. Normally,  *fruit* is uncountable. *“We bought some fruit in the market”*. *“Eating fruit and vegetables is good for you”* etc. I would say the verb ***break*** is more commonly used, e.g. “Nowadays, a plastic bag is more likely to *break* when it's carrying heavy stuff.” Lastly, a street comprises  of the ground, there's no need to say “street's ground” just say “street” or “ground”.

> The plastic bag **broke**/**ripped** and the **fruit**, which was inside, fell onto the **ground**
>    The plastic bag **broke**/**ripped** and the fruit fell to the **street**.

If someone wanted to say why the fruit was on the ground, or what happened after the bag broke, they could say

> 1. The fruit was on the ground because the bag (holding it) **broke**.
> 2. The fruit fell onto the sidewalk when the plastic carrier [bag] got **broken/torn/ripped**.
> 3. The fruit was on the ground because the bag was **broken/torn/ripped**.

I feel that *broke* and *ripped* are only interchangeable in sentences 1  while in #2 and #3 any of the terms mentioned above could be used.

Answer (score 1):

As a leading adjective, *a **torn** shirt / bag / sheet* beats out *a **ripped** one* by [a huge margin...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20torn%20shirt%2Ca%20ripped%20shirt&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20torn%20shirt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20ripped%20shirt%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...but "post-positioned" [*It **was torn** / It **was ripped***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bag%20was%20torn%2Cbag%20was%20ripped&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbag%20was%20torn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbag%20was%20ripped%3B%2Cc0) are much more equally favoured...

[image]

Offhand I can only think of ***tear [someone] off a strip*** *([criticize someone angrily for doing something wrong](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tear-someone-off-a-strip-tear-a-strip-off-someone))* as an example context where ***rip*** can't naturally replace ***tear***. But that's an idiomatically established collocation, and I'm not even sure exactly how or why it relates to the sense of ***rend / split / pull apart***.

---

TL;DR: Both versions are fine, and mean *exactly* the same thing. So just use whichever you prefer.

But note that *...because the bag **was** ripped/torn* implies the bag was ***already*** defective before the failed attempt to use it to carry fruit, whereas *...because the bag **ripped/tore*** implies it was the weight of the fruit that caused the problem.